# How to retrieve active IE tab's url in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have the following code in VB.Net to get IE tabs' url:

```
Function getIEUrl() As List(Of String)
    Try
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        Dim sw As New ShellWindows()
        For Each browser As InternetExplorer In New ShellWindows()
            list.Add(browser.LocationURL)
        Next
        Return list
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

How can I manage it to get only the Active tab's url?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done much regarding accessing other programs data, but a quick Google search put me on to this website:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10112922/how-to-get-current-active-tab-handle-in-an-ie7-window-using-c.aspx

From what I understand, you need to iterate through each tab process in IE and find the active one. Having the active one, you then grab the URL.

Comment: I guess there is no better solution than iterate through each and find it so I accepted your answer. Thanks!